# Weather Live - elegant weather background / full screen app options?

Tags: windows, windows-8

[Weather Live](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/weather-live/id755717884?mt=12) is a sleek and useful app for OS X that presents weather in a useful and attractive full screen fashion.  See the background app here where I have underlaid it behind Radar In Motion and a webcam monitor to give a hand weather console:
[image: Example of Weather Live used as a background]

Are there any such Windows applications that can be customized to this same styling to offer a background to other foreground apps in a similarly visually appealing layout?